# How to write the hashCode() function for a cyclic graph node?

Tags: java, eclipse, hashcode

I have the following class that is used as part of a graph :

```java
public class MyNode {

    private String name;

    private Set<MyNode> parents;

    private Set<MyNode> children;

    // getters and setters
}
```

When I use Eclipse's `Source / Generate hashCode() and equals()`, it generates this method:

```java
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((children == null) ? 0 : children.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((parents == null) ? 0 : parents.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that this method goes from the current object to its children, then **while computing the hashCode() of the first child**, it gets back to the original node through the `parents.hashCode()` but don't know that the hashCode() has already been computed there. It then reenters the `children` of the original node, and it gives a beautiful infinite loop.

**Question** : how can I check that two instances of `MyNode` are the same object while, at the same time, avoid the infinite loop? Is this acceptable to add a `visited` boolean in the MyNode class, for the purpose of stopping the exploration? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: The `visited` would have to be changed back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use children or parents of node when implementing `hashCode` and `equals`. They are mutable properties. Calculation of `hashCode` will differ after changing edges and will result in broken Maps and Set collections.

Implement `hashCode` and `equals` using only immutable fields that makes a distinct natural key for an object. A name might be a good candidate, unless it can be changed.

If no immutable fields exists, either:

1. Don't override `hashCode` and `equals` methods, defaults will be fine. It will make each class instance unique.
2. Make some unique id field (by sequance) and use it as a seed in `hashCode` and comparison in `equals`.

Comment: But what if two nodes have the same immutable fields while not being at the same place in the graph?

Comment: Um... default is *not* fine in most applications, because the default implementation basically gives you a different number per instance. I.e. no two instances are the same, not even when they have the exact same data.

Comment: +1 to Stropboskop. It's very important the equals() and hashcode() honor their contracts with each other. In this case, I think you'd want to just hash on the node name.

Comment: @geceo If two nodes have the same key fields, that means it should be the same node. It is a problem of deciding what are the key fields for an object, not a implementation of `equals` or `hashCode`.

Comment: @Stroboskop If you don't have fields that are good for calculating `equals` and `hashCode`, default is good. If you don't have the key fields, the each instance is distinct.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether two objects are the same instance using the `==` opearator:

```
if(obj0 == obj1)
```

If you want to use a `visited` flag you should implement it using a lookup (a `Map` for example) since after your code runs you have to reset those flags.

I suggest ignoring `parents`/`children` and adding an unique **id** to each node instead.

Comment: He can probably get away with using visited and a cached value if the "visited" flag is cleared in a try{ /*recurse*/ } finally { visited=false;}

Answer (score 2):

The only hard requirement on `hashCode()` is that two objects which are equal must return the same hash value.

This implementation would comply:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 42;
}
```

...because nothing says that non-equal objects MUST have different hashcodes.

Of course, to do its job properly, `hashCode()` will work better if values can be spread out. You can do anything you like as long as you don't break the rule about equal objects. In normal general-purpose code where I don't expect the hashes to be critical to performance, I generally just return the hashcodes of a significant field or two (eg name in this case), provided that those fields are involved in the computation of equality such that equal objects have the same hash.

The point is, you really need to consider `equals` and `hashCode` as a pair, and it's better to start with your definition of equals.

Comment: @geceo Be aware of the danger, your Set of nodes will become very slow as all of nodes will be hold within one bucket of the hashtable inside Set implementation.

Comment: Sure - I'm not suggesting that he actually use the "42" implementation, I'm just using it as an example to demonstrate that hashCode doesn't have to be complicated.